# How do I start a new SMS conversation?

Tags: sms

All the messages I ever exchange with one number are listed as one conversation. How do I start a new conversation with someone on the same number?

If this is an organisational thing, then I'd like to be able to use it as one and genuinely treat new subjects as new conversations. Or not to be told that every message I ever send someone is part of one long conversation when it isn't.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't particularly want to have to delete my entire message conversation with that person just to get rid of an error message; if anyone knows another way to get rid of the 'failed' I'd appreciate that too.

You don't, you just have to delete the message that is failing. Long press it, choose "Delete".

> How do I start a new conversation with someone on the same number?

How do you expect your phone to understand what messages belong in which category? The only way I see this working is if there's a function to put "all messages from now on" in a separate conversation, but that's not a feature that exists in the standard SMS application, and not in any app that I know of.

Dividing your past messages with a contact in two parts makes no sense, it would be even harder to find a message then if you can't remember what "conversation" you've put it in. Not only would you have to scroll back to see it, you would also have to pick the right category. Surely it's easier to sort the messages on a by-contact basis and just scroll.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on the failed message; I just worked out how to do this at the same time.

Comment: And putting all messages from a certain point in a new conversation is exactly what I want. It makes perfect sense to me - when you're emailing back and forth with someone, do you just hit reply every time? Or when you're starting a new subject, do you start a new conversation? When I'm reading through old messages and the conversation goes from being about something serious to being about sausages... that's the point where I'd like to declare that to be the next conversation. And when it returns to something serious, the one after that.

Comment: The problem is that the division you are used to works with e-mails, because e-mails have subjects. With SMS, there's no way of knowing what "conversation" a message would belong to. Ofcourse you could categorize it subjectively on your phone in the actual app, but I'm not sure if that's a very sought after feature. You could look around the custom SMS apps available, there's a bunch.

Comment: But the current situation is just a chronological listing of all the texts I've exchanged with one person. Many of these things already don't belong together as a conversation, so why are they being listed as one? I'm happy to have 'list all texts from one person' as an option, but if someone's going to call it a 'conversation' I'd like to be able to treat it as one, and end it like the end of a phone call - purely on the basis of chronology.

Comment: If you don't require posterity (to take the phone call analogy) you can always delete your discussion history every time you see the discussion as ended ;)

Comment: *grins* Yeah... Not quite what I'm looking for either. I'll stick with being annoyed by the name, then, and look around for alternatives. Ta!

Comment: Just call it a 'history' instead of a 'conversation'.